# OptimisticLockException when removing entity in openJPA mySQL

Tags: java, mysql, openjpa

I use `OpenJPA 2.4.0` on `MySQL`

I have 3 tables - `meeting`, `location`, `meeting_location`.

`meeting_location` is a join table, which has 1 foreign key to `meeting`, and 2 to `location` - `main_location_id` and `secondary_location_id`.

I initialize the tables with the following parameters, and then attempt to delete the entry from the `meeting` table.

```
    id  loc_name    
------  ------------
     0  location 0  
     1  location 1  
     2  location 2  
     3  location 3  
     4  location 4  
     5  location 5  
     6  location 6  
     7  location 7  
     8  location 8  
     9  location 9  


         id  name       
------  -----------
     1  meeting 1  


             id  meeting_id  main_location_id  secondary_location_id  name    
------  ----------  ----------------  ---------------------  --------
     1           1                 4                      9  (NULL)  
     2           1                 2                      7  (NULL)  
     3           1                 0                      5  (NULL)  
     4           1                 3                      8  (NULL)  
     5           1                 1                      6  (NULL)
```

When I try to call

```
entityManager.remove(meeting)
```

I get an `org.apache.openjpa.persistence.OptimisticLockException`:

```
org.apache.openjpa.persistence.OptimisticLockException: Optimistic locking errors were detected when flushing to the data store.  
The following objects may have been concurrently modified in another transaction: 
[com.test.StackOverflowQuestionTest.MeetingLocation-3, 
com.test.StackOverflowQuestionTest.MeetingLocation-5, 
com.test.StackOverflowQuestionTest.MeetingLocation-1, 
com.test.StackOverflowQuestionTest.MeetingLocation-2, 
com.test.StackOverflowQuestionTest.MeetingLocation-4]
```

**Hereby the full test listings:**

**SQL:**

```
  /*Table structure for table `meeting` */
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `meeting`;
CREATE TABLE `meeting` (
  `id`                          INT(16) NOT NULL,
  `name`                VARCHAR(128),
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)

)
  ENGINE =INNODB
  DEFAULT CHARSET =utf8;


        /*Table structure for table `location` */
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `location`;
CREATE TABLE `location` (
  `id`                          INT(16) NOT NULL,
  `loc_name`            VARCHAR(128),
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)

)
  ENGINE =INNODB
  DEFAULT CHARSET =utf8;

  /*Table structure for table `meeting_location` */
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `meeting_location`;
CREATE TABLE `meeting_location` (
  `id`                          INT(16) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `meeting_id`          INT(16) NOT NULL,
  `main_location_id`        INT(16) NOT NULL,
  `secondary_location_id`       INT(16) NULL,
  `name`                VARCHAR(128),

  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `meeting_location_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`meeting_id`) REFERENCES `meeting` (`id`)
ON DELETE  CASCADE
ON UPDATE  CASCADE      
  ,
  CONSTRAINT `meeting_location_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`main_location_id`) REFERENCES `location` (`id`)
ON DELETE  CASCADE
ON UPDATE  CASCADE        
  ,
  CONSTRAINT `meeting_location_ibfk_3` FOREIGN KEY (`secondary_location_id`) REFERENCES `location` (`id`)
    ON DELETE  CASCADE
ON UPDATE  CASCADE  
)
  ENGINE =INNODB
  DEFAULT CHARSET =utf8;
```

**Entities**:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="location")
public class Location {
    @Id
    @Column(columnDefinition="INT")
    private int id;

    @Basic
    @Column(name="loc_name", length=128)
    private String locName;

    public Location() {
    }

    public Location(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getLocName() {
        return locName;
    }

    public void setLocName(String locName) {
        this.locName = locName;
    }
}


@Entity
@Table(name="meeting")
public class Meeting {
    @Id
    @Column(columnDefinition="INT")
    private int id;

    @OneToMany(targetEntity=MeetingLocation.class, mappedBy="meeting", cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set meetingLocations = new HashSet();

    @Basic
    @Column(length=128)
    private String name;


    public Meeting() {
    }

    public Meeting(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Set getMeetingLocations() {
        return meetingLocations;
    }

    public void setMeetingLocations(Set meetingLocations) {
        this.meetingLocations = meetingLocations;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}


@Entity
@Table(name="meeting_location")
public class MeetingLocation {

    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="main_location_id", columnDefinition="INT", nullable=false)
    private Location mainLocation;

    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="secondary_location_id", columnDefinition="INT")
    private Location secondaryLocation;

    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="meeting_id", columnDefinition="INT", nullable=false)
    private Meeting meeting;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(columnDefinition="INT")
    private int id;

    @Basic
    @Column(length=128)
    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Location getMainLocation() {
        return mainLocation;
    }

    public void setMainLocation(Location mainLocation) {
        this.mainLocation = mainLocation;
    }

    public Location getSecondaryLocation() {
        return secondaryLocation;
    }

    public void setSecondaryLocation(Location secondaryLocation) {
        this.secondaryLocation = secondaryLocation;
    }

    public MeetingLocation() {
    }

    public MeetingLocation(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }


    public Meeting getMeeting() {
        return meeting;
    }

    public void setMeeting(Meeting meeting) {
        this.meeting = meeting;
    }
}
```

**Unit Test:**

```
@ManagedBean
public class SOQuestionTest extends BaseTest {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getInstance(LogCategory.OPENEJB_STARTUP_CONFIG, SOQuestionTest.class);
    public static final int MEETING_ID = 1;
    public static final String MEETING_1 = "meeting 1";

    @Resource
    protected UserTransaction transaction;

    @Inject
    private EndUnitDao<EntityManager> alertDao;

    @PersistenceContext(name = "euComm-pu")
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Test
    public void SOExampleTest() {

        try {
            transaction.begin();

            Meeting meeting = new Meeting();
            meeting.setName(MEETING_1);
            meeting.setId(MEETING_ID);

            int mainLocationsSize = 5;

            List<Location> locations = new ArrayList<Location>();
            for (int i = 0; i < (mainLocationsSize * 2); i++) {
                Location location = new Location();
                location.setLocName("location " + i);
                location.setId(i);
                locations.add(location);
                entityManager.persist(location);
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < mainLocationsSize; i++) {
                MeetingLocation meetingLocation = new MeetingLocation();
                meetingLocation.setMainLocation(locations.get(i));
                meetingLocation.setSecondaryLocation(locations.get(mainLocationsSize + i));
                meetingLocation.setMeeting(meeting);
                meeting.getMeetingLocations().add(meetingLocation);
            }
            entityManager.persist(meeting);

            this.transaction.commit();

            Meeting meeting1 = entityManager.find(Meeting.class, MEETING_ID);
            Assert.assertEquals(MEETING_1, meeting1.getName());

            this.transaction.begin();
            Meeting meeting2 = entityManager.find(Meeting.class, MEETING_ID);
            //Here I get the OptimisticLockException:
            entityManager.remove(meeting2);
            this.transaction.commit();

            Meeting meeting3 = entityManager.find(Meeting.class, MEETING_ID);
            Assert.assertNull(meeting3);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            Assert.fail(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

- BaseTest is an utility class we use to manage transactions, logging and other common tasks .

**Logs:**

```
5057  test-pu  TRACE  [main] openjpa.jdbc.SQL - <t 1394557075, conn 1722642791> executing prepstmnt 1491251091 SELECT t0.loc_name FROM location t0 WHERE t0.id = ? [params=(int) 0]
5057  test-pu  TRACE  [main] openjpa.jdbc.SQL - <t 1394557075, conn 1722642791> [0 ms] spent
5058  test-pu  TRACE  [main] openjpa.jdbc.SQL - <t 1394557075, conn 1722642791> executing prepstmnt 1280539125 SELECT t0.loc_name FROM location t0 WHERE t0.id = ? [params=(int) 5]
5058  test-pu  TRACE  [main] openjpa.jdbc.SQL - <t 1394557075, conn 1722642791> [0 ms] spent
5058  test-pu  TRACE  [main] openjpa.jdbc.SQL - <t 1394557075, conn 1722642791> executing prepstmnt 323248196 SELECT t0.loc_name FROM location t0 WHERE t0.id = ? [params=(int) 1]
5059  test-pu  TRACE  [main] openjpa.jdbc.SQL - <t 1394557075, conn 1722642791> [1 ms] spent
5059  test-pu  TRACE  [main] openjpa.jdbc.SQL - <t 1394557075, conn 1722642791> executing prepstmnt 1301992318 SELECT t0.loc_name FROM location t0 WHERE t0.id = ? [params=(int) 6]
5059  test-pu  TRACE  [main] openjpa.jdbc.SQL - <t 1394557075, conn 1722642791> [0 ms] spent
5060  test-pu  TRACE  [main] openjpa.jdbc.SQL - <t 1394557075, conn 1722642791> executing prepstmnt 2052728503 SELECT t0.loc_name FROM location t0 WHERE t0.id = ? [params=(int) 4]
5060  test-pu  TRACE  [main] openjpa.jdbc.SQL - <t 1394557075, conn 1722642791> [0 ms] spent
5060  test-pu  TRACE  [main] openjpa.jdbc.SQL - <t 1394557075, conn 1722642791> executing prepstmnt 1414992442 SELECT t0.loc_name FROM location t0 WHERE t0.id = ? [params=(int) 9]
5061  test-pu  TRACE  [main] openjpa.jdbc.SQL - <t 1394557075, conn 1722642791> [0 ms] spent
5061  test-pu  TRACE  [main] openjpa.jdbc.SQL - <t 1394557075, conn 1722642791> executing prepstmnt 1812214031 SELECT t0.loc_name FROM location t0 WHERE t0.id = ? [params=(int) 2]
5061  test-pu  TRACE  [main] openjpa.jdbc.SQL - <t 1394557075, conn 1722642791> [0 ms] spent
5062  test-pu  TRACE  [main] openjpa.jdbc.SQL - <t 1394557075, conn 1722642791> executing prepstmnt 760487425 SELECT t0.loc_name FROM location t0 WHERE t0.id = ? [params=(int) 7]
5062  test-pu  TRACE  [main] openjpa.jdbc.SQL - <t 1394557075, conn 1722642791> [0 ms] spent
5062  test-pu  TRACE  [main] openjpa.jdbc.SQL - <t 1394557075, conn 1722642791> executing prepstmnt 518757980 SELECT t0.loc_name FROM location t0 WHERE t0.id = ? [params=(int) 3]
5063  test-pu  TRACE  [main] openjpa.jdbc.SQL - <t 1394557075, conn 1722642791> [1 ms] spent
5063  test-pu  TRACE  [main] openjpa.jdbc.SQL - <t 1394557075, conn 1722642791> executing prepstmnt 779932859 SELECT t0.loc_name FROM location t0 WHERE t0.id = ? [params=(int) 8]
5063  test-pu  TRACE  [main] openjpa.jdbc.SQL - <t 1394557075, conn 1722642791> [0 ms] spent
5064  test-pu  TRACE  [main] openjpa.jdbc.SQL - <t 1394557075, conn 1722642791> executing prepstmnt 604225989 DELETE FROM location WHERE id = ? [params=(int) 0]
5064  test-pu  TRACE  [main] openjpa.jdbc.SQL - <t 1394557075, conn 1722642791> [0 ms] spent
5065  test-pu  TRACE  [main] openjpa.jdbc.SQL - <t 1394557075, conn 1722642791> executing prepstmnt 1653474307 DELETE FROM location WHERE id = ? [params=(int) 5]
5065  test-pu  TRACE  [main] openjpa.jdbc.SQL - <t 1394557075, conn 1722642791> [0 ms] spent
5065  test-pu  TRACE  [main] openjpa.jdbc.SQL - <t 1394557075, conn 1722642791> executing prepstmnt 4677559 DELETE FROM meeting_location WHERE id = ? [params=(int) 3]
5065  test-pu  TRACE  [main] openjpa.jdbc.SQL - <t 1394557075, conn 1722642791> [0 ms] spent
5070  test-pu  TRACE  [main] openjpa.jdbc.SQL - <t 1394557075, conn 1722642791> executing prepstmnt 1283267007 DELETE FROM location WHERE id = ? [params=(int) 1]
5073  test-pu  TRACE  [main] openjpa.jdbc.SQL - <t 1394557075, conn 1722642791> [3 ms] spent
5073  test-pu  TRACE  [main] openjpa.jdbc.SQL - <t 1394557075, conn 1722642791> executing prepstmnt 1004931143 DELETE FROM location WHERE id = ? [params=(int) 6]
5077  test-pu  TRACE  [main] openjpa.jdbc.SQL - <t 1394557075, conn 1722642791> [4 ms] spent
5078  test-pu  TRACE  [main] openjpa.jdbc.SQL - <t 1394557075, conn 1722642791> executing prepstmnt 1040066455 DELETE FROM meeting_location WHERE id = ? [params=(int) 5]
5086  test-pu  TRACE  [main] openjpa.jdbc.SQL - <t 1394557075, conn 1722642791> [8 ms] spent
5086  test-pu  TRACE  [main] openjpa.jdbc.SQL - <t 1394557075, conn 1722642791> executing prepstmnt 885018785 DELETE FROM location WHERE id = ? [params=(int) 4]
5087  test-pu  TRACE  [main] openjpa.jdbc.SQL - <t 1394557075, conn 1722642791> [1 ms] spent
5087  test-pu  TRACE  [main] openjpa.jdbc.SQL - <t 1394557075, conn 1722642791> executing prepstmnt 851514585 DELETE FROM location WHERE id = ? [params=(int) 9]
5088  test-pu  TRACE  [main] openjpa.jdbc.SQL - <t 1394557075, conn 1722642791> [1 ms] spent
5088  test-pu  TRACE  [main] openjpa.jdbc.SQL - <t 1394557075, conn 1722642791> executing prepstmnt 1158016054 DELETE FROM meeting_location WHERE id = ? [params=(int) 1]
5088  test-pu  TRACE  [main] openjpa.jdbc.SQL - <t 1394557075, conn 1722642791> [0 ms] spent
5088  test-pu  TRACE  [main] openjpa.jdbc.SQL - <t 1394557075, conn 1722642791> executing prepstmnt 2065936034 DELETE FROM location WHERE id = ? [params=(int) 2]
5089  test-pu  TRACE  [main] openjpa.jdbc.SQL - <t 1394557075, conn 1722642791> [1 ms] spent
5090  test-pu  TRACE  [main] openjpa.jdbc.SQL - <t 1394557075, conn 1722642791> executing prepstmnt 1432547991 DELETE FROM location WHERE id = ? [params=(int) 7]
5092  test-pu  TRACE  [main] openjpa.jdbc.SQL - <t 1394557075, conn 1722642791> [2 ms] spent
5092  test-pu  TRACE  [main] openjpa.jdbc.SQL - <t 1394557075, conn 1722642791> executing prepstmnt 49365994 DELETE FROM meeting_location WHERE id = ? [params=(int) 2]
5094  test-pu  TRACE  [main] openjpa.jdbc.SQL - <t 1394557075, conn 1722642791> [2 ms] spent
5094  test-pu  TRACE  [main] openjpa.jdbc.SQL - <t 1394557075, conn 1722642791> executing prepstmnt 429407697 DELETE FROM location WHERE id = ? [params=(int) 3]
5095  test-pu  TRACE  [main] openjpa.jdbc.SQL - <t 1394557075, conn 1722642791> [1 ms] spent
5096  test-pu  TRACE  [main] openjpa.jdbc.SQL - <t 1394557075, conn 1722642791> executing prepstmnt 2020466851 DELETE FROM location WHERE id = ? [params=(int) 8]
5106  test-pu  TRACE  [main] openjpa.jdbc.SQL - <t 1394557075, conn 1722642791> [10 ms] spent
5107  test-pu  TRACE  [main] openjpa.jdbc.SQL - <t 1394557075, conn 1722642791> executing prepstmnt 520296852 DELETE FROM meeting_location WHERE id = ? [params=(int) 4]
5107  test-pu  TRACE  [main] openjpa.jdbc.SQL - <t 1394557075, conn 1722642791> [0 ms] spent
5107  test-pu  TRACE  [main] openjpa.jdbc.SQL - <t 1394557075, conn 1722642791> executing prepstmnt 549803608 DELETE FROM meeting WHERE id = ? [params=(int) 1]
5108  test-pu  TRACE  [main] openjpa.jdbc.SQL - <t 1394557075, conn 1722642791> [1 ms] spent
Aug 31, 2015 12:45:11 PM org.apache.geronimo.transaction.manager.TransactionImpl beforeCompletion
WARNING: Unexpected exception from beforeCompletion; transaction will roll back
<openjpa-2.4.0-nonfinal-1598334-r422266:1599166 nonfatal store error> org.apache.openjpa.persistence.OptimisticLockException: Optimistic locking errors were detected when flushing to the data store.  The following objects may have been concurrently modified in another transaction: [com.test.StackOverflowQuestionTest.MeetingLocation-3, com.test.StackOverflowQuestionTest.MeetingLocation-5, com.test.StackOverflowQuestionTest.MeetingLocation-1, com.test.StackOverflowQuestionTest.MeetingLocation-2, com.test.StackOverflowQuestionTest.MeetingLocation-4]
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.BrokerImpl.newFlushException(BrokerImpl.java:2359)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.BrokerImpl.flush(BrokerImpl.java:2207)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.BrokerImpl.flushSafe(BrokerImpl.java:2105)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.BrokerImpl.beforeCompletion(BrokerImpl.java:2023)
    at org.apache.geronimo.transaction.manager.TransactionImpl.beforeCompletion(TransactionImpl.java:527)
    at org.apache.geronimo.transaction.manager.TransactionImpl.beforeCompletion(TransactionImpl.java:512)
    at org.apache.geronimo.transaction.manager.TransactionImpl.beforePrepare(TransactionImpl.java:413)
    at org.apache.geronimo.transaction.manager.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:262)
    at org.apache.geronimo.transaction.manager.TransactionManagerImpl.commit(TransactionManagerImpl.java:252)
    at org.apache.openejb.core.CoreUserTransaction.commit(CoreUserTransaction.java:67)
    at com.test.shared.commons.BaseTest$Tx.tx(BaseTest.java:121)
    at com.test.StackOverflowQuestionTest.SOQuestionTest.SOExampleTest(SOQuestionTest.java:106)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:80)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:714)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:901)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1231)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:127)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:111)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:767)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:617)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:334)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:329)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:291)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:240)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1198)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1123)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1031)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.run(RemoteTestNG.java:111)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:204)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:175)
    at org.testng.RemoteTestNGStarter.main(RemoteTestNGStarter.java:125)
Caused by: <openjpa-2.4.0-nonfinal-1598334-r422266:1599166 nonfatal store error> org.apache.openjpa.persistence.OptimisticLockException: An optimistic lock violation was detected when flushing object instance "com.test.StackOverflowQuestionTest.MeetingLocation-3" to the data store.  This indicates that the object was concurrently modified in another transaction.
FailedObject: com.test.StackOverflowQuestionTest.MeetingLocation-3
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.PreparedStatementManagerImpl.flushAndUpdate(PreparedStatementManagerImpl.java:124)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.BatchingPreparedStatementManagerImpl.flushAndUpdate(BatchingPreparedStatementManagerImpl.java:79)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.PreparedStatementManagerImpl.flushInternal(PreparedStatementManagerImpl.java:100)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.PreparedStatementManagerImpl.flush(PreparedStatementManagerImpl.java:88)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.ConstraintUpdateManager.flush(ConstraintUpdateManager.java:550)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.ConstraintUpdateManager.flush(ConstraintUpdateManager.java:120)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.BatchingConstraintUpdateManager.flush(BatchingConstraintUpdateManager.java:59)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.AbstractUpdateManager.flush(AbstractUpdateManager.java:104)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.AbstractUpdateManager.flush(AbstractUpdateManager.java:77)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.JDBCStoreManager.flush(JDBCStoreManager.java:732)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.DelegatingStoreManager.flush(DelegatingStoreManager.java:131)
    ... 36 more
NestedThrowables:
<openjpa-2.4.0-nonfinal-1598334-r422266:1599166 nonfatal store error> org.apache.openjpa.persistence.OptimisticLockException: An optimistic lock violation was detected when flushing object instance "com.test.StackOverflowQuestionTest.MeetingLocation-5" to the data store.  This indicates that the object was concurrently modified in another transaction.
FailedObject: com.test.StackOverflowQuestionTest.MeetingLocation-5
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.PreparedStatementManagerImpl.flushAndUpdate(PreparedStatementManagerImpl.java:124)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.BatchingPreparedStatementManagerImpl.flushAndUpdate(BatchingPreparedStatementManagerImpl.java:79)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.PreparedStatementManagerImpl.flushInternal(PreparedStatementManagerImpl.java:100)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.PreparedStatementManagerImpl.flush(PreparedStatementManagerImpl.java:88)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.ConstraintUpdateManager.flush(ConstraintUpdateManager.java:550)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.ConstraintUpdateManager.flush(ConstraintUpdateManager.java:120)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.BatchingConstraintUpdateManager.flush(BatchingConstraintUpdateManager.java:59)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.AbstractUpdateManager.flush(AbstractUpdateManager.java:104)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.AbstractUpdateManager.flush(AbstractUpdateManager.java:77)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.JDBCStoreManager.flush(JDBCStoreManager.java:732)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.DelegatingStoreManager.flush(DelegatingStoreManager.java:131)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.BrokerImpl.flush(BrokerImpl.java:2207)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.BrokerImpl.flushSafe(BrokerImpl.java:2105)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.BrokerImpl.beforeCompletion(BrokerImpl.java:2023)
    at org.apache.geronimo.transaction.manager.TransactionImpl.beforeCompletion(TransactionImpl.java:527)
    at org.apache.geronimo.transaction.manager.TransactionImpl.beforeCompletion(TransactionImpl.java:512)
    at org.apache.geronimo.transaction.manager.TransactionImpl.beforePrepare(TransactionImpl.java:413)
    at org.apache.geronimo.transaction.manager.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:262)
    at org.apache.geronimo.transaction.manager.TransactionManagerImpl.commit(TransactionManagerImpl.java:252)
    at org.apache.openejb.core.CoreUserTransaction.commit(CoreUserTransaction.java:67)
    at com.test.shared.commons.BaseTest$Tx.tx(BaseTest.java:121)
    at com.test.StackOverflowQuestionTest.SOQuestionTest.SOExampleTest(SOQuestionTest.java:106)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:80)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:714)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:901)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1231)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:127)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:111)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:767)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:617)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:334)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:329)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:291)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:240)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1198)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1123)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1031)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.run(RemoteTestNG.java:111)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:204)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:175)
    at org.testng.RemoteTestNGStarter.main(RemoteTestNGStarter.java:125)
```

Comment: The first explanation that i can see is that your first transaction is not committed when you try to remove the entity

Comment: I changed the transaction management to the UserTransaction to eliminate this concern, the same error occurs.

Answer (score 0):

From you logs :

```
5064  test-pu  TRACE  [main] openjpa.jdbc.SQL - <t 1394557075, conn 1722642791> executing prepstmnt 604225989 DELETE FROM location WHERE id = ? [params=(int) 0]
5064  test-pu  TRACE  [main] openjpa.jdbc.SQL - <t 1394557075, conn 1722642791> [0 ms] spent
5065  test-pu  TRACE  [main] openjpa.jdbc.SQL - <t 1394557075, conn 1722642791> executing prepstmnt 1653474307 DELETE FROM location WHERE id = ? [params=(int) 5]
5065  test-pu  TRACE  [main] openjpa.jdbc.SQL - <t 1394557075, conn 1722642791> [0 ms] spent
5065  test-pu  TRACE  [main] openjpa.jdbc.SQL - <t 1394557075, conn 1722642791> executing prepstmnt 4677559 DELETE FROM meeting_location WHERE id = ? [params=(int) 3]
```

The root cause is

```
cascade=CascadeType.ALL
```

The problem is that when you run

```
entityManager.remove(meeting2);
```

You are actually trying to DELETE all locations associted with it.
Because meeting2 has two meeting locations, it should fail (even if the second meeting location is not bound to another meeting!). JPA detects that by seeing you are trying to DELETE something you did not FETCH, that's why it throws the (maybe wrongly defined) OptimisticLockException.

A possible solution is to use another cascadetype which does not use DELETE.

If you don't want to delete locations, use cascadetype.PERSIST, or DETACH.